# How to enable the "Compress Shared Files" options in c# while zip the files?

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to zip all the files in one directory in C#. However, one file is used by another process and causing an exception like, "(that) file is in use by another process."

Here is the code:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Doc").ToList();
              
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Fastest);`
```

The thing is, I can manually zip all the files (including the file used by another process) in the 7Zip GUI iff I enable the "Compress Shared Files" option.

How can I set the same "Compress Shared Files" option from C# ?

Comment: It won't fix your problem, but the first thing I'd do is remove the `ToList()` call at the end of the first line. It doesn't help, and only servers to waste memory here.

Comment: What's the exception type you're getting? Are you sure the file is not open for exclusive writing somewhere?

Comment: I am getting IO exception (The Process cannot access the file)

Comment: @Sownthari and it still works with 7-Zip? I mean when you check that option it [explicitly opens files for shared read](https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip/blob/c0ea2281f88bd2306fe0b5c70f900a5ff8ceb635/CPP/Windows/FileIO.cpp#L438) and that should be possible to do by passing file stream opened with same flags with ZipArchive, still I see no signs of it opening files for exclusive IO.

Comment: @orhtej2 I tried by FileSharing option, I can read the text from that file (used by another process) but i can't create archive.CreateEntryFromFile from that file.

Comment: using (var fileStream = File.Open(file,
                                     new FileStreamOptions()
                                     {
                                         Access = System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                         Share = FileShare.ReadWrite 
                                     }))
                            {                               
                                zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileStream.Name,
                                    Path.GetFileName(file), CompressionLevel.Fastest);

Comment: @Sownthari so once you have file stream open copy it directly to new entry rather than using extension method CreateEntryFromFile, as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry?view=net-6.0#examples

Comment: @orhtej2 Yes i did like the same. var zipArchiveEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
                                using (var zipArchiveStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
                                {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
  fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    zipArchiveStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: @orhtej2 Yes I already did that way its works to me but I am looking any other possibilities like any other settings or something else to achieve directly instead of reading all content from that file and again write that content in zip file stream? Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can zip the files using DotNetZip third party library even if that files used by another process .

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddFiles(Directory.GetFiles(LogFilePath)), "Logs");

                zip.Save(memoryStream);
            }
```

[DotnetZip](https://www.encodedna.com/aspdotnet/create-zip-files-in-aspdotnet.htm)